# 6 random character prefix automatically added to entire DB tables, how / why?

Tags: database

I'm working on a site, live on server. I'm using Navicat for working with the DB.
I have the WP DB opened and am 100% sure the tables were just standard tables, using standard wp_ prefix.

While I'm working on another screen in admin area, I needed some user-meta info, I refresh the already opened DB.. and suddenly ALL tables have 6 random character prefix automatically added to entire DB tables!

So now instead of having one table.. **wp_usermeta** 
I now have.. **aojsfj_wp_usermeta**

Now, opening for example **aojsfj_wp_usermeta** is not a list of users, it's just ONE user's meta.
So now the DB has created all separate tables per the few (7) test user accounts, prefixing them with 6 random characters.

Can someone enlighten me on why / how this has happened? So far everything still seems to be working, but the DB + all these new tables can't be good!

Comment: looks like you used the built in wordpress installer that your hosting provides. Usually when using this tool on of the security features while installing WP is to change the table prefix, seems like this is the issue. Check with your hosting for more details

Answer (score 1):

Check your wp-config.php file and find $table_prefix = 'aojsfj_'; in it, if you replace the value to empty string you would be able to remove all prefix from all your tables.
Please note if you remove this from live website, it will ask you to reinstall your website.

Comment: The default prefix is 'wp_' not an empty string

Answer (score 0):

@Iviju @Buttered_Toast thank you guys very much for attempting to help me, much appreciated!

Well, I just returned to provide info on what the issue "was".. At first I was thinking it was some kinda hack via sql injection. BUT, that was not the case.

I am using the pro version of [WP Reset](https://wpreset.com/)

And as a part of its "Snapshot" feature (it makes exact duplicates of ALL of your tables right before you make any major changes, like install / remove any plugins, theme changes, etc.)

So all of my original wp_ tables are still there and intact, but the 6 character prefixes were and are a part of the backup / screenshot of the tables.

Just leaving this here incase someone else using WP Reset not knowingly comes across this.